# Блок с неправильным треугольником с градиентной заливкой

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

Есть задача cверстать вот такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сложность в том, что фон градиентный и высота блока меняется.
Первое, что приходит в голову это использовать `clip-path`.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```css
.message {
width: 250px;
padding:20px;
background-image: linear-gradient(219deg, #12a5b7 0%, #81c185 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 90%, 90% 90%, 100% 100%, 96% 90%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <p> uitmaakt? Van dit gebouw wordt je mede-eigenaar. De gevolgen hiervan zijn groot. je mag gebruik maken van alle gemeenschappelijke ruimtes van het gebouw. Echter, de keerzijde daarvan is dat je als mede-eigenaar uiteraard ook financieel verantwoordelijk
    bent voor het gebouw. Als eigenaar van een appartement ben je verplic</p>
</div>
```

Но в этом случае, при изменении высоты меняется и уголок.

Как можно решить данную задачу? Возможно без JS?

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое, на мой взгляд сделать это в SVG. 
Тултип будет адаптивным и одинаково выглядеть во всех браузерах, включая `Edge`, `IE11`

Ниже пример сделанный один в один с вашего скрина. Позиционировать его нужно, присвоив ему `position:absolute` относительно родительского блока которому необходимо присвоить `position:relative`

```css
message {
width: 20vw;
height:20vh;

}
```

```html
<div class="message">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="481" height="529" viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"> 
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="Grad1"  x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y1="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#58b798" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#13a5b6"/>
  </linearGradient>  
 </defs>
 
  <path  fill="url(#Grad1)" d="M1.6 1.2 481 0 480.3 499.7H461.6L481 529 430.3 499.7H1.6Z" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

Для размещения текста **внутри SVG** используется тег [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) , что позволяет реализовать перенос текстовых строк, как в HTML.

```css
.wrap {
width: 30vw;
height:20vh;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="Grad1"  x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y1="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#58b798" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#13a5b6"/>
  </linearGradient>  
 </defs>
 
  <path  fill="url(#Grad1)" d="M1.6 1.2 481 0 480.3 499.7H461.6L481 529 430.3 499.7H1.6Z" />
   <foreignObject x="30" y="20"  width="400px" height="390px"
   style="font-size:32px; overflow: hidden">

<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="message"  >
    Van dit gebouw wordt je mede-eigenaar. De gevolgen hiervan zijn groot. je mag gebruik maken van alle gemeenschappelijke ruimtes van het gebouw. Echter, de keerzijde daarvan is dat je als mede-eigenaar uiteraard ook financieel verantwoordelijk
    bent voor het gebouw. 
  
</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg> 
</div>
```

Приложение адаптивно и работает одинаково во всех современных браузерах, включая **Edge**

Comment: У меня не получилось по вашему примеру сделать тултипы разной высотой.

Comment: @Григорий У меня получилось :) А что у вас не получилось? В svg разная высота обеспечивается разными параметрами path

Comment: Получается если высота окна зависит от содержимого, нужно будет её высчитывать и менять параметры path?

Comment: @Григорий в вопросе вы однозначно определили, что делать без JS/  А вот частично менять определенные параметры path без JS никак.  Если у вас текст тултипа не меняется динамически, а вы его определяете один раз при верстке, то я считаю, что мой вариант вполне подойдет. Он адаптивный и работает во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 2):

Если задать стрелку в пикселях, то проблем при ресайзе не будет:

```css
.message {
  width: 450px;
  padding:20px;
  --b: calc(100% - 25px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(219deg, #12a5b7 0%, #81c185 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% var(--b), 
    var(--b) var(--b), 
    100% 100%, 
    calc(100% - 10px) var(--b), 
    100% var(--b), 
    100% 0%, 
    0% 0%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <p> uitmaakt? Van dit gebouw wordt je mede-eigenaar. De gevolgen hiervan zijn groot. je mag gebruik maken van alle gemeenschappelijke ruimtes van het gebouw. Echter, de keerzijde daarvan is dat je als mede-eigenaar uiteraard ook financieel verantwoordelijk
    bent voor het gebouw. Als eigenaar van een appartement ben je verplic</p>
</div>
```

Comment: в FF работает (+), в Edge видно только прямоугольник

Comment: @Alexandr_TT угу, в нем никогда ccs clip-path и не работал

Answer (score 2):

### Bonus

Хочу добавить несколько примеров тултипов

На мой взгляд можно рассмотреть вот такой интересный вариант - тултипа с со стрелкой и вырезами вокруг неё.

```css
.wrap {
width: 100vw;
height:100vh;

}
.message {
color:#FFFAEA;
font-size:5px;
max-width:90%;
padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="Grad1"  x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y1="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#58b798" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#13a5b6"/>
  </linearGradient>  
 </defs>
 
  <path  fill="url(#Grad1)" d="m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10L41.4 80.2 37.3 75.7c-2.4-2.3 0.9-4 2-2.2L59.9 95.1 80.3 73.3c1.6-1.7 3.7 0.5 1.9 2.1L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z" />
   <foreignObject x="12" y="12"  width="100px" height="100px" >

<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="message"  >
    Van dit gebouw wordt je mede-eigenaar. De gevolgen hiervan zijn groot. je mag gebruik maken van alle gemeenschappelijke ruimtes van het gebouw. Echter, de keerzijde daarvan is dat je als mede-eigenaar uiteraard ook financieel verantwoordelijk
    bent voor het gebouw. De gevolgen hiervan zijn groot.
  
</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg> 
</div>
```

**Пример анимации этого тултипа**

```css
.wrap {
  height:70vh;
  width:70vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="Grad"  x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y1="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="dodgerblue" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
  </linearGradient>  
 </defs>
 
  <path  d="m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z" style="fill:url(#Grad);stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round; fill-opacity:0.5">
          <animate id="an_path"
          attributeName="d"
          values="m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;
      m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10L41.4 80.2 37.3 75.7c-2.4-2.3 0.9-4 2-2.2L59.9 95.1 80.3 73.3c1.6-1.7 3.7 0.5 1.9 2.1L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10l21.4 0.2-0.1-0.1c4.2 0.1 11.3 0.1 11.3 0.1l7.7 0 8.9 0c16.6 0 7.2-2 5.5-0.3L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z;
      m20 10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 10l0 50c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10L41.4 80.2 37.3 75.7c-2.4-2.3 0.9-4 2-2.2L59.9 95.1 80.3 73.3c1.6-1.7 3.7 0.5 1.9 2.1L78 80.2 100 80c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10l0-50c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10z"
          begin="svg1.click"
          dur="5s"
          repeatCount="1"
          fill="freeze"
          restart="whenNotActive">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <text x="30" y="50" font-size="18" fill="white">click me </text>
</svg> 
</div>
```

**Примеры тултипа с различным расположением треугольника**

1. Треугольник расположен внизу

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50vw" height="50vh" viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad"  x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#58b798" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#13a5b6"/>
    </linearGradient>  
 </defs> 
 <path  d="m9.5 71.7c0-13.7 11.6-32.5 25.4-32.5 148.2 0 296.4 0 415.3 0 13.7 0 25.4 18.8 25.4 32.5 0 156.3 0 266.5 0 385.2 0 14.2-11.2 34.1-25.4 34.1-53.8 0-180.7 0-180.7 0l-21.4 28.5-19.8-28.5c0 0-118.3 0-193.4 0-14.2 0-25.4-19.9-25.4-34.1 0-121.9 0-258.2 0-385.2z" style="fill:url(#Grad)"/>
</svg>
```

2. Вверху

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50vw" height="50vh" viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad"  x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#13a5b6" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#58b798"/>
    </linearGradient>  
 </defs> 
 <path  d="m475.5 487.4c0 13.7-11.6 32.5-25.4 32.5-148.2 0-296.4 0-415.3 0-13.7 0-25.4-18.8-25.4-32.5 0-156.3 0-266.5 0-385.2 0-14.2 11.2-34.1 25.4-34.1 53.8 0 180.7 0 180.7 0l21.4-28.5 19.8 28.5c0 0 118.3 0 193.4 0 14.2 0 25.4 19.9 25.4 34.1 0 121.9 0 258.2 0 385.2z" style="fill:url(#Grad)"/>
</svg>
```

3. Слева

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50vw" height="50vh" viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad"  x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#13a5b6" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#58b798"/>
    </linearGradient>  
 </defs> 
 <path  d="m448.1 46.6c13.7 0 32.5 11.6 32.5 25.4 0 148.2 0 296.4 0 415.3 0 13.7-18.8 25.4-32.5 25.4-156.3 0-266.5 0-385.2 0-14.2 0-34.1-11.2-34.1-25.4 0-53.8 0-180.7 0-180.7L0.4 285.1 28.9 265.3c0 0 0-118.3 0-193.4 0-14.2 19.9-25.4 34.1-25.4 121.9 0 258.2 0 385.2 0z" style="fill:url(#Grad)"/>
</svg>
```

4. Справа

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50vw" height="50vh" viewBox="0 0 481 529" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
 <linearGradient id="Grad"  x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#58b798" /> 
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#13a5b6"/>
    </linearGradient>  
 </defs> 
 <path  d="M34.9 512.7C21.1 512.7 2.4 501.1 2.4 487.4 2.2 339.2 2.1 190.9 2 72.1 2 58.3 20.8 46.7 34.5 46.7 190.8 46.6 301 46.5 419.7 46.4c14.2 0 34.1 11.2 34.1 25.3 0 53.8 0.1 180.7 0.1 180.7l28.5 21.4-28.5 19.8c0 0 0.1 118.3 0.1 193.4 0 14.2-19.9 25.4-34.1 25.4-121.9 0.1-258.2 0.2-385.2 0.3z" style="fill:url(#Grad)"/>
</svg>
```